# translate element inside link on hover

Tags: css, sass, transform, css-transitions, translate-animation

I'm trying to use a CSS3 transitions to translate an object horizontally to the right. It seems very simple but maybe I'm missing something...

This is what I have:

```
<h1>
    <a href="#" class="qa">Check Q&amp;A<i class="icon-right-open-gal"></i></a>
</h1>
```

The `i` is an image placed with a sprite. I would like this element to be displaced horizontally to the right once the link is hovered.

```css
.qa{

  &:link,&:visited{
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 18px;
    // @include background-image(linear-gradient(bottom, #42BA70, #49CB7A));
    background-color: #E3560D;
    @include box-shadow(inset 1px 1px rgba(255,199,170,0.5));
    @include box-sizing(border-box);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    @include transition-property(all);
    @include transition-duration(0.2s);
    @include transition-timing-function(ease-in-out);

    i{
    font-size: 13px;
    }

    span{
      font-family: helvetica-neue, helvetica, serif;
      font-size: 15px;
    }
  }


  &:hover, &:active{
    background-color: #F77902;
    @include box-shadow(inset 1px 1px rgba(248,255,170,0.5));

      i{
      -webkit-transform: translateX(40px);
      -moz-transform: translateX(40px);
      -o-transform: translateX(40px);
      transform: translateX(40px);
      }
  }
```

I tried several options but none are working. Could somebody how to use it correctly. I'm using SASS for this project. I left the translate property without a compass mixing to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that the `<i>` tag is inline. It needs a layout in order to be translated. To do so just give it a `display: inline-block` attribute and all is good. See this simple fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WxqCw/

Comment: Thanks! it worked. I;ve foudn myself more than one time with this issue of now knowing what is inline or not. Do you know of any documentation which is good to learn what inline elements are and which elements are inline? P.D. It worked for me but the fiddle does not work for now...

Comment: sorry about the fiddle. about learning which is inline/block elements i would suggest looking at mdn : [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element)

Comment: here's the pertinent links on there: [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Inline_elements) [block elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements)